# How to make one state only can be entered once?

Tags: angularjs

I have two states in ui-router. One is 'welcome' and the other is 'home'.

Is it possible to enter state 'welcome' only at the first time of launching the app and cannot enter it anymore ?

To make it more clearly:

*. user install the app and launch
*. app enter state 'welcome'
*. app enter state 'home' via a button in 'welcome'

After that, the app cannot go back to 'welcome' any more, including via the hardware back button (android) or launch the app again.

Any ideas of how to achieve that?

Comment: When the user enters the first state first time save a variable in localStorage. Next time when the app loads check localstorage and redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first route `welcome`

Inside the controller, set a variable in `localStorage`

```
app.controller("FirstController", function($scope, $state) {
    if(localStorage.getItem("didVisited")) {
        $state.go("home");
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem("didVisited", true);
    }
});
```

I've used it in my `ionic` app as well. It works!

Even better would be to check the `localStorage` in your `run` method itself.

```
app.run(function($state) {
    if(localStorage.getItem("didVisited")) {
        $state.go("home");
    } 
});
```

Now set the variable in `localStorage` inside the homeController